# Fabric-js object setWidth() and setHeight() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

i have problem with Fabric.js (http://fabricjs.com) library that i cant solve for many hours... im trying programaticaly change dimensions of image with methods setWidth() and setHeight() (http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.Object.html) but it didnt work properly, dimensions of control borders are changed fine but image is still in same size, you can see it on screenshot:
[image: fabric.js javascript jquery object width height problem]

can someone help me? btw when im trying to change dimensions with scaleToHeight() or scaleToWidth() it works good, so problem must be in that two methods above ... im using version 0.8.8, thx for any help!

Comment: This was a bug. Fixed in https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/af67423df9e14e92f6fa9c4c1d47541d1a634889